# Can not get a key value from Firebase storage in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I cannot get a key value from firebase storage while datas exist in storage.

```
key = intent.getStringExtra("key").toString()
```

and they return `null`

```
binding.writebtn.setOnClickListener {
        val title = binding.titleArea.text.toString()
        val contents = binding.contentArea.text.toString()
        val uid = FBAuth.getUid()
        val time = FBAuth.getTime()
        val key = FBRef.boardRef.push().key.toString()
        FBRef.boardRef
            .child(key)
            .setValue(BoardModel(uid, title, contents, time))
```

and this is my saving function.

[image]

and as u can see, all datas are saved properly. But still I cannot get a key value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The name of the images in Storage are present on the Realtime Database? If yes, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from any database you need to use any clinter (Retrofit) if you have this code please share otherwise check this thread. The GetStringExtra() you are currently using is for getting shared data between android core components and it has nothing to do with firebase database.